# "undo your comment upvote" is missing in app?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, voting, android-app

There is an option to *undo the comment upvote* in stack exchange sites like an alert

[image]

Whereas using Stack exchange app, I'm able to upvote a comment but unable to undo it.
[image]

I think instead of showing Vote up again, it should show message like *"undo upvote"*.  Something similar in stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been around for a long time now but I just added a confirmation alert to match the one from the website.